# Chrome 80 how to decode passwords and cookies

Tags: c++, google-chrome, security, cryptography, aes

Until Chrome 80, the passwords and Cookies can be decrypt only with the WindowsAPI `CryptUnprotectData` function (Like used [here](https://github.com/adnan-alhomssi/chrome-passwords/blob/master/src/chrome-passwords.cpp)). But from Chrome 80, the security has change like explain [here](https://xenarmor.com/how-to-recover-saved-passwords-google-chrome/). But I have some diffuculties moving from theory to practice.

As explained, I started by getting the key from the `Local State` file. I decode it from base64 and decrypt it with `cryptUnprotectData`. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what's next. I don't understand what the history of `12-byte random IV data` and `v10` implies, and how to do it from a practical point of view. How does this step work ? I've tried with the Sodium lib, but it fail :

```cpp
void decrypt(const unsigned char *cryptedPassword, std::string &masterKey){
    std::string str{reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cryptedPassword)};
    const std::string iv = str.substr(3, 12);
    const std::string payload{str.substr(15)};
    unsigned char decrypted[payload.length()];
    unsigned long long decrypted_len;
    crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt(
            decrypted, &decrypted_len,
            NULL,
            reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(payload.c_str()), payload.length(),
            reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(iv.c_str()), iv.length(),
            reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(crypto_aead_aes256gcm_NPUBBYTES),
            reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(masterKey.c_str())
    );
    std::cout << "decrypted: " << decrypted << std::endl;
}
```

```
Error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant (it is about the definition of decrypted)
```

But I can't set it has constant because the length is unknown before it run.

Moreover, I have huge doubts about the success of this algorithm, even without this problem.

Comment: Someones demo-ing non-portable, non-Standard code. Replace the Variable Length Array with a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The last thing you want in crypto code is the ability for the user to specify an arbitrary length and then have fun with the resulting stack overflow. `vector` will prevent that.

Comment: Nope. I'm wrong. Use a `std::string`. the `vector` is a nuisance to print out again at the end.

Comment: Of course, `std::vector<unsigned char>` is probably a best thing to use here. But `crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt` need a `unsigned char *`.
edit: same problem with `std::string`.

Comment: You can easily convert `std::vector<unsigned char>` to an `unsigned char*` (see `std::vector::data`)